# Android (java) Create Dynamic UI based upon Same Volley API Response (JSON)

Tags: java, android, android-volley, response

I am using Android Java with Volley GET Request that returns JSON. This request accepts various parameters, based upon these parameters the response is calculated and sent back.

The API GET Request fetches class students' marks of a particular subject. The parameters define class and subject and based upon these different columns response is sent back.

For example, class ONE subject Mathematics has two columns result
[image: Class ONE Mathematics Result]

and class ONE English has 7 columns of the result
[image: CLASS ONE ENGLISH]

I am using RecyclerView which has a predefined row layout with static header fields/columns to display data.

This is just an example, the criteria vary for different classes and subjects.

Here is my volley API call

```
String url = getString(R.string.api_url) + "grandtest_marks/?BranchClassID="+branchClassID
            +"&ExamTypeID="+examTypeID+"&SubjectName="+subjectValue+"&SectionID="+sectionID;

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            response -> {
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                //populate recyclerview here to show grand test marks
                // Do something with response, Process the JSON
                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        //for different criteria I'll have different columns how should I incorporate that?
                        //get single student's marks
                        grandTestMarksModel = new GrandTestMarksModel(
                                Integer.toString(i+1),
                                jsonObject.getString("StudentName"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test1Marks"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test2Marks"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test3Marks"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test4Marks"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test5Marks"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Test6Marks")
                        );

                        grandTestMarksModels.add(grandTestMarksModel);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(viewGrandTestMarksAdapter);

                    } //for
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //catch

            },
            error -> {
                // this block will respond wrong registration no or password or any other network error
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request timed out.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your internet connection and then try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Parse Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.put("Authorization", getMyJWT());
            return headers;
        }
    };
    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView (which would be obvious option for everyone) but there are some setbacks to it. But there are many View Architecture which would be better to use. Something like Epoxy or Litho can be used. These both are mostly widely used.

Comment: As mentioned, I am using RecyclerView which has a predefined row layout with static header fields/columns to display data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are different View Architectures which can be used - something like Epoxy or Litho for dynamic View.